# Summing/grouping unique rows in a table

Tags: r

Edited: As suggested by @Ben I have changed the code but getting an error.
I need to bring it in to format like:

Date Confirmed_cum

25/01/2020 4
26/01/2020 4

Can anyone help?

```
covid <- read.csv(file = 'covid_au_state.csv')
dput(covid)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
covid %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%       
  summarize(confirmed_cum = sum(confirmed_cum)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =confirmed_cum , y = date)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = confirmed)) + 
  labs(x = 'Confirmed cases', y = 'date', 
       title = 'Number of new confirmed cases daily throughout Australia')
```

console output

```
covid <- read.csv(file = 'covid_au_state.csv')
dput(covid)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
covid %>%
 mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>% 
 group_by(date) %>%        
 summarize(confirmed_cum = sum(confirmed_cum)) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x =confirmed_cum , y = date)) + geom_point(aes(color = confirmed)) + 
 labs(x = 'Confirmed cases', y = 'date', title = 'Number of new confirmed cases 
 daily throughout Australia')
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'confirmed' not found
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: How shall I add a dataset ?  Like this `dput(covid.csv)`?

Comment: First do `covid <- read.csv(file = 'covid_au_state.csv')`. Then do `dput(covid)`. This will produce an output in your console that can be pasted into your question. If your data set is large, provide a reproducible sample like `dput(head(covid, n = 20))` or `dput(sample(covid, size = 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to calculate the sum of `confirmed_cum` for each dat and then plot that. Without your data, it is hard to know for sure this will work, but here is something that might work. It requires the `lubridate` and `dplyr` packages.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
covid %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date)) # makes dates both pretty and functional
  group_by(date) %>%       # groups data by each date
  summarize(confirmed_cum = sum(confirmed_cum)) # sum this column by date
```

This code returns a new data.frame with one row per date and the total of `confirmed_cum` for that date. To plot it with `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
covid %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%       
  summarize(confirmed_cum = sum(confirmed_cum)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =confirmed_cum , y = date)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = confirmed_cum)) + 
  labs(x = 'Confirmed cases', y = 'date', 
       title = 'Number of new confirmed cases daily throughout Australia')
```

Comment: Here is the data set link on gsheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IqlHbfqHEMVCobpOoY31UBKivSGlP7A8KPdw3ix5ask/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes I am trying to group the dates and add the `column(confirmed_cum )`. I tried your code but It shows an error `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: Then you need to paste in your data to your question using `dput()` so I can reproduce your error. Do not link to your data - links don't last for ever.

Comment: Have a look again in the question. Is it right format now?

Comment: @ManinderPreetSinghPuri - Thanks. That let me find the mistake in my answer. I had a missing pipe operator `%>%`. Try now.

Comment: Thanks. But it still shows an error. Have a look in question I edited the error.

Comment: Thanks it works. Cheers! I do have another question if you don't mind asking. How do I highlight the max points.. I used `geom_point(aes(color = confirmed)) + 
  points(x[y >= 600], y[y >= 600], pch = 4, col = "red", cex =2) +
  labs`  but it shows no change in the plot, Why?